# Error when calling a function using route

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I've wrote this function to insert an "account" in the database:

```
(defn create-account [accountnumber]
  (if (= nil (find-by-number accountnumber))
    (jdbc/insert! db-spec :accounts {:accountnumber accountnumber})
    nil
  ))
```

This tests passes, so the function it's working:

```
  (testing "create and find-by-number account"
    (account/create-account 10)
    (is (= 10 ((account/find-by-number 10) :accountnumber)))
  )
```

But when I try to use this route:

```
(defroutes app-routes
      (GET "/:account" [account] (account/create-account account))
      (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
    rmp/wrap-params
    wrap-json-response
    wrap-json-body))
```

I got this error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
>
> ERROR: column "accountnumber" is of type integer but expression is of
>   type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the
>   expression.

Verifying types, I can see that when I run the test, accountnumber type is java.lang.Long and when it comes from routes, it's type is java.lang.String, I've tried to convert it but got no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the route is returning a param. Params are strings.

If you change your route to be something like this:

`(defroutes app-routes
      (GET "/:account" [account] (account/create-account (Integer/parseInt account)))
      (route/not-found "Not Found"))`

it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by adding conversion to Long:
`(GET "/:account" [account] (account/create-account (Long/valueOf account)))`
Which one is better in this case?

Comment: I would say that the solution you used is better.  It's more explicit that you want it to be a long.  The big difference between `valueOf` and `parseLong` is that the latter returns a primitive and the former returns a `new Long`